# Move and rename files based on subfolders

Tags: bash, unix, directory, rename, move

I would appreciate any help, relatively new here

I have the following directory structure

```
Main_dir
|-Barcode_subdirname_01\(many further subfolders)\filename.pdf
|-Barcode_subdirname_02\(many further subfolders)\filename.csv
```

- There are 1000s of files within many subfolders
- The first level sub directories have the barcode associated to all files within. eg 123456_dirname
- I want to copy all files within all subfoders to the main_dir and
  rename the files **subdirname_barcode_filename.extension** (based only on the first subdirectory name and barcode)

I've been attempting to write a bash script to do this from the main_dir but have hit the limit of my  coding ability (i'm open to any other way that'll work).

- firstly identifying the first level sub folders

  `find -maxdepth 1 -type d |`
- then cut out the first 2 parts deliminated by the underscores

  `cut -d\_ -f1 > barcode`
- then find the files within the subfolders, rename and move

  `find -type f -print0 |
     while IFS= read -r filenames; do
     newname="${barcode/sudirname/filename\/}"
     mv "filename" "main_dir"/"newname"
   done`

  I can't get it to work and may be headed in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename` with `sed` like substitute conventions, for example

```
$ rename 's~([^_]+)_([^_]+)_.*/([^/.]+\..*)~$1_$2_$3~' barcode_subdir_01/a/b/c/file2.csv
```

will rename file to

```
barcode_subdir_file2.csv
```

I used `~` instead of the more common `/` separator to make it more clear.

You can test the script with `-n` option to show the renamed files without actually doing the action.